# Subsequent While Loop not able to refresh database query

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy

Am running a script which fetches data from the database once every 2 seconds and then passes the results off to a function that creates several threads and works on the returned data.

My query returns items that are both marked `is_deleted = False` in the database. In the code below, if say I have one Member in the database and I either mark them as deleted or even I actually delete them, I expect the `member.get_member()` to return "None" which I handle with the `if statement`. Problem though is that even if I delete that Member from the database while the script is already running, it bring back "data" while it should bring back "None". If I stop the script and run it again, it then fetches the correct data as it returns "None"

Am running Python3.2 with sqlAlchemy 0.8

```
def main():
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        member = Member()
        myData, instance_counter = member.get_member()
        if myData == None:
            print("No member registered yet:", get_time_now())
        else:
            myqueuing(instance_counter, myData)   
            dbase.session.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer through trial and error. Run `session.close_all()` just before you execute the database query again as seen below.

What am not sure of is if the `session.close_all()` will close even sessions that are being run by the threads that are invoked to work on the fetched data. If it will close those sessions then its back to the drawing board and I need your help.

```
def main():
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)

        #This solved it but am not sure if it will close other sessions 
        #that have been spawned by the threads
        dbase.session.close_all()  

        member = Member()
        myData, instance_counter = member.get_member()
        if myData == None:
            print("No member registered yet:", get_time_now())
        else:
            myqueuing(instance_counter, myData)   
            dbase.session.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```